# Adding Hand-Built Models to an EDMX

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm following an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714955.aspx) on applying the Repository Pattern and the Unit Of Work Pattern to Entity Framework, but I'm stuck at the mapping between the custom-made domain models and the as-yet-nonexistant database.

The article has me create two simple POCOs, `Employee` and `TimeCard`.  It also walks through creating generic repositories and custom implementations therein.  (I'm using the custom repositories so I can try to keep EF dependencies in the data access assembly.)  However, they sort of glaze over an important step in the mapping.  The article says:

> With the POCOs in place we can create an Entity Data Model (EDM) in Visual Studio (see figure 1). We will not use the EDM to generate code for our entities. Instead, we want to use the entities we lovingly craft by hand. We will only use the EDM to generate our database schema and provide the metadata EF4 needs to map objects into the database.

The "Figure 1" it references is here:
[image: EDM Figure 1]

But that's all it says on the subject.  There's an aside on how to generate POCOs from an EDMX.  There's lots of information via Google on how to generate POCOs, generate EDMX from a database, etc.  But in this walk-through we already have the POCOs and I need to use them in the EDMX which would, in turn, generate the database (I'm assuming, based on other code-first walk-throughs).

I've added an "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" to the project, which is basically a blank canvas.  But I'm not seeing how to add my existing POCOs to that canvas.  Do I have to re-create them manually on the design surface (which would be a pretty significant duplication problem in a larger domain)?  If so, how do they map to the existing ones?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that directly (at least not without some add-in tool or something). What about generating the DB with the POCOs and then `Update Model From Database`?

Comment: @HighCore: That might work. On an upcoming project I imagine there's going to be some divergence between the DB and the Models, and it's probably ideal to have an actual DB project in Visual Studio to manage it. If I were to generate the EDMX from the DB (which at this point in the question would be indistinguishable from hand-crafting the EDMX), how would it then be mapped to the existing models?

Comment: I guess that mapping is not needed because you already have the entities and the context in code, and the EDMX is only used as a Store-to-Entities mapping

Comment: @HighCore: It's worth a try, I suppose.  I'm not comfortable with there being a "magic layer" in the code.  Seems like a pretty big hole in the MSDN walk-through...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically when you use the designer the flow is the opposite - you create the model with the designer (or create/update the model from the database) and then the code is created for you. The created code can be either the EF1 style code with entities derived from EntityObject and attributes etc. which is created with a Single File Generator which is a part of VS (Code Generation Strategy set to "Default"*) or the code can be created with T4 templates (Code Generation Strategy set to "None"*) in which case you need to add T4 templates to your project. EF matches POCOs with Entities from the edmx file by convention (names of entities have to be the same, names and types of properties have to match etc.). In the article for some reason they went the opposite way which is weird since it requires that you create all the entities and relationships with the designer manually (since the designer does not know how to create entities from the code) and make sure that the requirements for the conventions (you may not even be aware of some of them) are met. However when you start with code the better approach is to use the EF Code First approach and skip the designer entirely. Code First can create database from your code. It also contains migrations feature which allows evolving your database along with your code. Finally (as you seem to use Visual Studio 2010) you could use EF6 which allows using all the goodness that was previously only available on .NET Framework 4.5 to be used on .NET Framework 4. See here for more details: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/

*the names are going to change in the new version designer that supports EF6 and works with Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013

**EDIT to address questions from the comment**

If you would like to use Code First would use the DbContext API which is a streamlined wrapper of the ObjectContext API. Here is a [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542) that should help get you started.
You can still use Code First if you have an existing database - the difference is that you will not be able to use migrations. The easiest way to get started with this is to use EF Power Tools. Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj572367) tutorial to see how to do that.
More help [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ef)

Comment: The article uses VS2010, but I'm using 2012 so some of the new tooling is available in my case. If I can skip the designer entirely (which I'd prefer), then how do I get EF to persist the models into a database?  What if there's already a database and I need to map to it, not by convention but more manually?